# How to get bounced emails details in php

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I have code written in php to fetch all the bounced emails details. But if i echo my message variable i am getting blank. How can we get the details.
Note: My account is gmail i wanted to track bounced emails.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';

$username = '********';

$password = '******';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if($emails) {

   $output = '';

   rsort($emails);

   foreach($emails as $email_number){

      $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

      $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.1)); 

      $header = imap_header($inbox, $email_number,0); 

      $from = $overview[0]->from;

      $header = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $email_number,0);

      $output= $message;

    }

}
imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

Can we get from and to email- ids.

Comment: You cannot assume the message body is always in "1.1"